# Understanding "V'haya"

Tags: midrash, parashat-lech-lecha

Being that the Medrash Rabba (Vayikra 11:7) explains every mention of the word "v'haya" refers to simcha, how can we understand Bereshis (12:12) where the pasuk begins with v'haya yet continues with a discussion of the dangerous fate of Avraham and Sara entering Mitzrayim?

Answer (score 1):

The [Midrash Vayikra Rabbah 11:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.11?lang=en) says the following:

(*Sources provided by [Sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org)*)

> .אתא ר' ישמעאל: עבדה פלגא, כל מקום שנאמר ויהי אין שמחה, והיה אין צרה
>
> *Rabbi Yishmael came (and said): Do half <sup>1</sup>, any place where it says ויהי there is not Joy, (and here it says) והיה there isn't suffering*

(*The following is my humble opinion, please take it with a grain of salt*)

It is to be noted that by [the Akeda](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22?lang=bi), [Rashi](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.5?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he) comments on the verse ([22:5](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22?lang=bi))

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אַבְרָהָ֜ם אֶל־נְעָרָ֗יו שְׁבוּ־לָכֶ֥ם פֹּה֙ עִֽם־הַחֲמ֔וֹר וַאֲנִ֣י וְהַנַּ֔עַר נֵלְכָ֖ה עַד־כֹּ֑ה וְנִֽשְׁתַּחֲוֶ֖ה וְנָשׁ֥וּבָה אֲלֵיכֶֽם׃
>
> *Then Abraham said to his servants, “You stay here with the donkey and I and the lad wil go up there and we will worship and return to you"*

the following:

> ונשובה: נִתְנַבֵּא שֶׁיָּשׁוּבוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם
>
> *ונשובה **AND WE WILL COME BACK** — He prophesied that they would both return (Genesis Rabbah 56).*

It could be also here that *Avram also prophesied* that they would both be safe and benefit from this venture.

By [12:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12?lang=bi), though it was dangerous for both Avram and Sarai, the result of the venture ultimately lead to Avram amassing much wealth (as demonstrated in [12:16](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) without Sarai or him being harmed in the venture (see [12:17-20](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) with Rashi and the [Chizkuni](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.17?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni,%20Genesis&lang2=he) on [12:17](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)). That being said, it could be reasonable why the word "והיה" is used.

Hope this is insightful.

<sub><sup>1</sup> See context discussed there.</sub>